# Where did we come out at/end up at

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

My mom was showing me around the city, so that I don't get lost and I know my way around when I'm alone. She kept asking me where we were.  We were driving down a narrow street with huge buildings all around. When that street ended, a "T-junction":

> Can you tell me where we came out at?
>
> Can you tell me where we ended up at?

What sounds natural "come out" or "end up"?

And can these be used when we are driving down a narrow street with no huge buildings around but a field?

Comment: In other words the street we were driving on was too narrow and was flanked by large buildings, and that road led to a wider and larger road.(the narrow street ended)@Michael Harvey

Answer (score 0):

Please note: in AmE, there is a lot of appending "at" at the end of sentences, like so:

> - Tell me where we're at. [very commonly heard, "at" appended at the end]
>
> That ***at*** is not necessary because we have:
>
> - Tell me where we are. [location, literal or figurative]
> - We are at a difficult moment in our lives.
> - We are at the school.

Now, for a T-junction:

- Tell me where we came out.
- Did you come out **at the right place**?
- Tell me where you ended up.
- Did you end up **at the right place**?

The T-junction examples with **come out** and **end up** do not require at at the end.

So, depending on how you want your speech to sound (more standard or less standard), watch your "ats". To sound more standard (which for some people means to sound better), only use at for location in statements and do not append it at the end of questions.

Comment: So does "come out" sounds natural? Is it common?

Comment: And will you use it for "closed places" only or for open roads as well?

Comment: I have already answered your questions. If something hadn't sounded right, I would have told you. at is used for locations of any kind. [Do you use it, not will you use it]

Comment: So it specifically means "where have we come", right?

Comment: No, come out does not mean come. I suggest you look up the phrasal verbs: to come out and end up.

Comment: "Come out" wasn't used in any of the Dictionaries in this sense. So what does it exactly mean?

Comment: If you are driving in some place, to come out at [some place] means to arrive there after driving. It is the end-point of your driving. He came out at/on the park.

Comment: come out suggests going through a place; end up suggests that is the end point of your walking or driving.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you described, **came out** and **ended up** are essentially interchangeable. Both describe a place where you paused and took note of your location. There's no requirement to have tall buildings -- it can refer to any location.

When you **come out**, it often implies that you took some circuitous route to reach your destination, such as winding your way through a maze or a series of one-way streets.

Despite the word *end*, where you **ended up** doesn't have to be the end of your journey. It might mark the end of a subset of your journey, such as reaching a particular landmark.

Another answer goes into detail about not using **at**.

Comment: We walked for hours through the woods and came out on the road. It is not circuitous necessarily at all. We walked for hours through the woods and ended up on the road. It might very well be the end of their walking.

Comment: I said often, not always.  "After walking around for hours, we finally came out at the right spot."